# How do I create a form with UI similar to the default windows 7 picture folder view in a C# winform application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a Winform application wherein I need a form where thumbnails of images are seen with the name of the image below it.

I was able to develop the above requirement with the help of a PictureBox placed in a UserControl and added to my form programmatically.

Now, I want a feature where multiple images can be selected simultaneously and then deleted. Unfortunately, I am finding it very difficult.

Is there any easy way of solving this or any readymade control available?
[image]

Comment: Please also notice that the windows 7 OS automatically adds certain border to images for enhancing its look. How do I achieve that also?

Comment: Have you even take a look at the base components? What about a ListView? that is exactly the control used by the Explorer...

Comment: I tried, but multiple selection was a problem in it.

Comment: Did you try `PictureBox.CanSelect=true`?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.canselect.aspx

Comment: The problem is that there are multiple usercontrol on the form and each usercontrol has only one picturebox. How do I select multiple usercontrols.?

Comment: Add the code you have so we don't have to suggest all kind of solutions you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create this UI using ImageListView control available from the following article.

> ImageListView is a .NET 2.0 control for displaying a list of image files. It looks and operates similar to the standard ListView control. Image thumbnails are loaded asynchronously with a separate background thread. The look of the control can be completely customized using custom renderers.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43265/ImageListView

The latest control source code is available on

https://code.google.com/p/imagelistview/